# How to trigger edit on single click in R Shiny DT datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a Shiny app with an editable DT table. Everything is working perfectly on desktop: I double click on a cell, edit the value, the value is processed in the background, and the whole table is updated appropriately.

However, on Chrome for Android double-click doesn't seem to be an option, so I can't edit the cells in my table.

After much searching for solutions, I tried to add a callback to trigger a doubleclick on a single click, but it doesn't have any effect. I give a minimal example below.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage( mainPanel( DTOutput("table") ) )
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  NumDays <- 14
  DayNum <- seq_len(NumDays)
  DF <- data.frame(Day=DayNum, Week=((DayNum-1) %/% 7 + 1), Steps=rep(0, NumDays), row.names=NULL)
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('table')
  
  js <- "table.on('click', 'tr', function() { 
  table.cell(this).trigger('dblclick.dt');
  });"

  output$table <- renderDT(datatable(DF, rownames = FALSE, selection = list(mode = 'none'), editable = list(target='cell'), options = list(scrollY = 600, searching = FALSE, paging=FALSE, ordering=FALSE, info=FALSE), callback = JS(js)))
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('table')
  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$table_cell_edit
    i <- info$row;    j <- info$col+1;    v <- info$value
    currentvalue <- abs(as.numeric(v))
    DF[i, j] <<- currentvalue + 10
    replaceData(proxy, DF, rownames = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tweaked your example with a bit jquery and got it to work - also note I changed 'tr' to 'td':

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage( mainPanel( DTOutput("table") ) )
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  NumDays <- 14
  DayNum <- seq_len(NumDays)
  DF <- data.frame(Day=DayNum, Week=((DayNum-1) %/% 7 + 1), Steps=rep(0, NumDays), row.names=NULL)
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('table')
  
  js <- "table.on('click', 'td', function() { 
    $(this).dblclick();
  });"
  
  output$table <- renderDT(datatable(DF, rownames = FALSE, selection = list(mode = 'none'), editable = list(target='cell'), options = list(scrollY = 600, searching = FALSE, paging=FALSE, ordering=FALSE, info=FALSE), callback = JS(js)))
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('table')
  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$table_cell_edit
    i <- info$row;    j <- info$col+1;    v <- info$value
    currentvalue <- abs(as.numeric(v))
    DF[i, j] <<- currentvalue + 10
    replaceData(proxy, DF, rownames = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Great! I am curious. Could you please explain  briefly why this works and the OPs code does not?

Comment: My JS/jQuery skills are a bit shaky, so I'll admit there was some trial and error involved with this, but I can give an explanation a go! In the OP's code, there's this [datatables method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell()) to access the data of the cell that the user has clicked on - it's similar to this example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html). However, seeing as we want to trigger the js event of a double click on the clicked cell, we're not actually interested in pulling the data.

Comment: What my code does instead is pull the actual DataTables cell object by omitting the cell() method (note, using "td" here actually gives us the cell that was clicked, as it returns the column and row index, whereas "tr" just returns the row index). Then, I just use the [dblclick](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) method to trigger a double click on that specific cell and thus trigger the DT text edit feature. Voila! Hopefully that made some sense!

Comment: @Jan I made a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/lucaanholt/pen/eYMPXzq?editors=1112) that you can play around with - hopefully the console outputs will help clarify what the differences are!